# How can I properly reassign variables in a Javascript class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

I am trying to build a custom cursor in Javascript by drawing svgs. I am done with the class but I am trying to progress from that to a sort of page transition where I could get the color of my class to fill the screen on page change and then change it back to what it was formally after 300ms.

This is my class

```
export class Cursor2 extends Cursors{

  newDiagonal   = this.diagonalWindow() / 9;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.speed = !isTouchDevices ? 0.5 : 1;
    this.delta = !isTouchDevices ? 0.04 : 0.04;
    this.cursor = true;
    this.tinyCursor = false;
    this.init();
    this.loop();

    
  }


  transitionIn = async() =>  {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    
       setTimeout(() => {
        this.newDiagonal = this.diagonalWindow()
        
           resolve()
       }, 300)
    })

   
}

transitionOut = () =>  {
   
     this.newDiagonal = this.diagonalWindow() / 9
     
  
}
  setParamsParticles() {
    this.nbrParticles =  !isTouchDevices ? 800 : 300;
    this.radiusStart = this.newDiagonal;
    this.radiusDiff = 0;
    this.sorting = "desc";
    this.idGradient = "gradient";
    this.fillParticles = `url('#${this.idGradient}')`;
    this.gradientParticles = {
        color1:'#FBFF24',
        color2: '#FBFF24',
    };
  }

  drawGradient() {
    return `<defs>
      <linearGradient id=${this.idGradient}>
        <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="${this.gradientParticles.color1}" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="${this.gradientParticles.color2}" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>`
  }
}
```

New diagonal method is initially assigned to the diagonal window method divided by 9 which comes from cursor on the call of the transition in function it should be reassigned to just the diagonal window method. The transition out method is called after the transition in method. I cant get this to reassign and it still uses the variable as I have assigned it for the radiusleft in the setparamsarticle method.

I use this class in a useEffect hook like this

```
 React.useEffect(() => {

    const GlobalCursor = new Cursor2()
    GlobalCursor.transitionIn().then(() => {
      GlobalCursor.transitionOut()
  })
}, [location.pathname])
```

The cursors function just incase

```
export class Cursors{

  constructor() {
    this.container = document.querySelector(`#cursor-2`);
  
    
    this.links = document.querySelectorAll(`a`);
    this.link = this.links[2 - 1];
    this.boundsLinks = this?.link?.getBoundingClientRect();

    
    this.xStart = this.boundsLinks?.left + this.boundsLinks?.width/2;
    this.yStart = this.boundsLinks?.top + this.boundsLinks?.height/2;
    this.mouse = { x: this.xStart,y: this.yStart };
    this.pos = { x: this.xStart, y: this.yStart };
    this.diff = { x: null,y: null };
    this.tinyCursor = true;
    this.transitionParticles = false;
    this.cursor = false;
    this.activeLinks();
    this.mousemoveCursor();
    window.addEventListener('resize',(e) => this.init());
  }

  mousemoveCursor() {
    window.addEventListener(isTouchDevices ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',(e) => {
      this.updateCoordinates(e);
    },{ passive : true });
  }

  updateCoordinates(e) {
    if (e.type.match('touch')) {
      this.mouse.x = e.touches[0].clientX;
      this.mouse.y = e.touches[0].clientY;
    }
    else {
      this.mouse.x = e.clientX;
      this.mouse.y = e.clientY;
    }
  }

  setParamsDiffs(){
    this.diff.x = this.mouse.x - this.pos.x;
    this.diff.y = this.mouse.y - this.pos.y;
    this.pos.x += this.diff.x * this.speed;
    this.pos.y += this.diff.y * this.speed;
  }

  init() {
    this.tinyCursor ? this.setParamsCursor() : null;
    this.setParamsParticles();
    this.drawCursor();
  }

  loop() {
    this.setParamsDiffs();
    this.tinyCursor ? this.setTinyCursor() : null;
    this.setParticles();
    requestAnimationFrame( () => this.loop() );
  }


  drawCursor() {
    this.widthContainer = window.innerWidth;
    this.heightContainer = window.innerHeight;
    this.container.innerHTML =
      `<svg
        width="${this.widthContainer}"
        height="${this.heightContainer}"
        viewbox="0 0 ${this.widthContainer} ${this.heightContainer}"
        preserveAspectRatio="${this.preserveAspectRatio || "none"}"
        style="background:${this.backColor || "none"}; cursor:${this.cursor ? "default" : "none"};">
        ${this.gradientParticles ? this.drawGradient() : ''}
        ${this.maskCursor ? this.drawMaskCursor() : this.drawParticles()}
        ${this.drawTinyCursor()}
    </svg>`;
    this.svg = this.container.querySelector('svg');
    this.tinyCursor ? this.nodeCursors = this.container.querySelectorAll('.tiny-cursor circle') : null;
    this.particles = Array.from(this.container.querySelectorAll('.particles circle'));
    this.sorting === "desc" ? this.sortParticles() : null;
    this.points = Array(this.nbrParticles).fill().map((el,i) => {
      return {
        node: this.particles[i],
        x: this.pos.x,
        y: this.pos.y,
      }
    });
  }

  drawTinyCursor() {
    return `${this.tinyCursor ?
      `<g class="tiny-cursor">
        <circle
          r=${this.radiusCursorBack || 10}
          cx=${this.pos.x}
          cy=${this.pos.y}
          fill="${this.fillCursorBack || "none"}"
          fill-opacity="${this.fillOpacityCursorBack || 1}"
          stroke="${this.strokeColorCursorBack || "none"}"
          stroke-width="${this.strokeWidthCursorBack || 1}"
          stroke-opacity="${this.strokeOpacityCursorBack || 1}"
          style="transform-origin: ${this.pos.x}px ${this.pos.y}px">
        </circle>
        <circle
          r=${this.radiusCursor || 10}
          cx=${this.pos.x}
          cy=${this.pos.y}
          fill="${this.fillCursor || "white"}"
          fill-opacity="${this.fillOpacityCursor || 1}"
          stroke="${this.strokeColorCursor || "none"}"
          stroke-width="${this.strokeWidthCursor || 0}"
          stroke-opacity="${this.strokeOpacityCursor || 1}"
          style="transform-origin: ${this.pos.x}px ${this.pos.y}px">
        </circle>
     </g>` : ''}`
  }

  setTinyCursor() {
    this.rotate = `rotate(${ Math.atan2(this.diff.y, this.diff.x) * 180 / Math.PI }deg)`;
    this.squeeze = Math.min(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.diff.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.diff.y, 2)) / this.accelerator, this.maxSqueeze);
    this.scale = `scale(${1 + this.squeeze},${1 - this.squeeze})`;
    for (const [i,tinyCursor] of this.nodeCursors.entries()) {
      tinyCursor.setAttribute('cx', this.pos.x)
      tinyCursor.setAttribute('cy',this.pos.y)
      tinyCursor.style.transformOrigin = `${this.pos.x}px ${this.pos.y}px`;
      tinyCursor.style.transform = this.rotate + this.scale;
    }
  }

  drawParticles() {
    return `<g class="particles" filter=${this.filterParticles || "none"}>
      ${(() => {
        if (this.strokeGradient) {
          return `
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id=${this.strokeGradient.idStrokeGradient} x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color=${this.strokeGradient.color1} />
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color=${this.strokeGradient.color2} />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>`
        }
      })()}
      ${Array(this.nbrParticles).fill().map((_,i) =>
        `<circle
          r="${this.setRadiusParticles(i)}"
          cx=${this.pos.x} cy=${this.pos.y}
          fill="${this.fillParticles || "none"}"
          fill-opacity="${this.fillOpacityParticles || 1}"
          stroke="${this.strokeGradient ? `url(#${this.strokeGradient.idStrokeGradient})` : this.strokeColorParticles}"
          stroke-width="${this.strokeWidthParticles || 0}"
          stroke-opacity="${this.strokeOpacityParticles || 1}"
          id="${i}">
        </circle>`).join('')}
    </g>`
  }

  setParticles() {
    if (this.transitionParticles) {
      for (const [i,particle] of this.particles.entries()) {
        particle.setAttribute('cx',this.pos.x )
        particle.setAttribute('cy',this.pos.y);
        particle.style.transitionProperty = "cx,cy"
        particle.style.transitionDuration = `${this.transitionParticles.duration+i*this.transitionParticles.delay}ms `;
        particle.style.transitionTimingFunction = this.transitionParticles.easing;
      }
    }
    else {
      this.posTrail = { x: this.pos.x, y : this.pos.y }
      for (const [i,point] of this.points.entries()) {
        this.nextParticle = this.points[i + 1] || this.points[0];
        point.x = this.posTrail.x;
        point.y = this.posTrail.y;
        point.node.setAttribute('cx',this.posTrail.x )
        point.node.setAttribute('cy',this.posTrail.y);
        this.posTrail.x += (this.nextParticle.x - point.x) * (this.delta || 0.9);
        this.posTrail.y += (this.nextParticle.y - point.y) * (this.delta || 0.9);
      }
    }
  }

  sortParticles(){
    this.particlesD3 = d3.selectAll(this.particles);
    this.particlesD3.data(this.particlesD3._groups[0].map((particle) => { return Number(particle.id) }));
    this.particlesD3.sort(d3.descending);
  }

  setRadiusParticles(i) {
    this.radius = null;
    if(this.directionRadius === ">"){
      this.radius = this.radiusStart-(i*this.radiusDiff);}
    else{
      this.radius = this.radiusStart+(i*this.radiusDiff);}
    this.radius > 0 ? this.radius = this.radius : this.radius = 0;
    return this.radius;
  }

  diagonalWindow() {
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;
    return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(this.width*this.width + this.height*this.height));
  }

  activeLinks() {
    this.activeClass = 'active';
    for (const link of this.links) { link.classList.remove(this.activeClass) };
    this.link?.classList.add(this.activeClass);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what behaviour you expect to see? Also, could you edit your code samples down to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @Dakeyras What I want to achieve is to get the this.newDiagonal value to this.radiusStart. The value only seems to be available within those function scopes. I can see it when I call the functions on the console but the radiusStart value still remains whats declared initially.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve this by making newDiagonal a static variable and passing the values through the methods.